# I have a left image and right image I want to apply to same css object, but their properties conflict with one another

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want both of these css styles to apply to the jumbotron text object, but only one or the other does and I cannot think of a way to combine them since they have competing properties.  The little image file (jumbotron_ribbon.png and jumbotron_ribbon_left.png) creates a little "flag" at the end of the button that says "The Washington Post" on it.  I want the little flag on the left AND the right, not just one or the other.

```css
.jumbotron_text .btn:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  right: -11px;
  top: 5px;
  width: 9px;
  height: 25px;
  background-image: url(../images/jumbotron_ribbon.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top right;
  background-color: #505050;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.jumbotron_text .btn:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -11px;
  top: 5px;
  width: 9px;
  height: 25px;
  background-image: url(../images/jumbotron_ribbon_left.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top right;
  background-color: #505050;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Jumbotron -->
<section class="full_width jumbotron">
  <div class="row jumbotron_text" data-animated="fadeIn">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 margbot30 clearfix">
      <div class="content">
        <span>alpha beta</span>
        <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm" href="javascript:void(0);" alt="">The Washington Post</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 margbot30 clearfix">
      <div class="content">
        <span>gamma delta</span>
        <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm" href="javascript:void(0);" alt="">The Washington Post</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 margbot30 clearfix">
      <div class="content">
        <span>epsilon alpha</span>
        <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm" href="javascript:void(0);" alt="">The Washington Post</a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
<!-- //Jumbotron -->
```

Comment: I tried to make you a snippet. Please add relevant code to make a [mcve] It is not clear what your code does you do not want

Comment: instead of both css sections having: .jumbotron_text .btn:before  I changed one to:  .jumbotron_text .btn:after as recommended below and that fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

It is completely useless to use the exact same selector ( `.jumbotron_text .btn:before` ) more than one time.

The element it target will just have the background-image that is lower in your css. The same goes for any other identical properties. And if the properties aren't identical, you should just regroup them under one css selector.

If you want to target something else, you want to use **another** selector.

Maybe you can try your luck with the `:after` selector.

Comment: The after worked and fixed the issue.  Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad I helped. You can then mark the answer as accepted if it works for you.